# in wordpress ACF ... how to filter the post type based on what is selected in relationship field

Tags: wordpress, filter, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I have a sport website . 
in it ... there is the championship post type ... 
for this "championship post type" ... I create a group of custom fields using ACF .

**this files have ( the important part )**

- **relationship filed :** select the teams in the championship .
- **repeater for games :** in each of them you select 2 teams as ( post object )

.

for exmple ... 
in the system I have teams [ A , B , C , D , E , F , G , H ... Z ]

I create championship with teams [ A , B , C , D ] ( select them in the relationship filed)
when I go to create a game repeater and go to the post object to select team1 
I get all the teams in the system ie:[ A , B , C , D , E , F , G , H ... Z ]

**BUT** I want to get only the team selected in the repeater [ A , B , C , D ]

*how I can make the post object show only items selected in the relationship filed . in same custom fields group . ?*

photo of the fields may help : 
[image]

I am open to change the structure of the custom field types . or any solution .
THANKS :)

Comment: REALLY no answer ...

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem ?